# Device provisioned with DPS always shown as "X509 self-signed" instead of "Certificate Authority"

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk, azure-iot-hub-device-management, azure-iot-dps

I try to set an Azure DPS with the authentication type "x509 CA certificate".
Everything works except the IoT hub shows devices provisioned with DPS as **"X509 self-signed" instead of "Certificate Authority"**.

[pic](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/assets/65221297/551e2658-9da2-4c79-af57-1281362ed9ad)

With devices directly created on IoT Hub (NOT via DPS), authenticated types are set to **Certificate Authority.** This is the behavior I want to reproduce with devices created from DPS.

[pic](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/assets/65221297/bcbcff18-afdd-4c17-ade5-f1d9c8b9d542)

My DPS enrollment group settings:

[pic](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/assets/65221297/bcbcff18-afdd-4c17-ade5-f1d9c8b9d542)

For testing, I'm using the IoT-Sdk-CSharp and follow this [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/previews/v2/provisioning/device/samples/solutions/BestPracticeSampleX509).

Do you know what I have to change in DPS for my devices to appear with the "Certificate Authority" authentication type?

Thank you for your help.
Have a nice day.

Comment: Refer this Tutorial Create a root certificate authority and use it to create subordinate CA and client certificates that you can use for testing purposes with [Azure IoT Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-x509ca-overview#authenticate-devices-signed-with-x509-ca-certificates)

Comment: Yes I followed all the steps, it works correctly with manually created devices on IoT Hub

Comment: AFIK, we have to  manually create

Comment: Are you sure ? Because in [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/previews/v2/provisioning/device/samples/solutions/BestPracticeSampleX509) tutorial (only available on c# sdk), they use DPS and CA certificate

Comment: Refer to this Provision multiple X.509 devices using enrollment [groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/tutorial-custom-hsm-enrollment-group-x509?tabs=linux&pivots=programming-language-csharp)

Comment: Once you get a valid certificate from a trusted Certified Authority, the authentication for the devices will display as 'X509 CA Signed' instead of 'Self-Signed X509 Certificate'. Please refer this resource X.509 certificate [attestation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/concepts-x509-attestation)

Comment: The provided script, X509DpsSetup.ps1 creates X.509 test certificates. They are provided for demonstration purposes only and MUST NOT be used for production. For a production environment, we recommend using X.509 certificate authority (CA) certificates and your own best practices for certificate lifetime management in [waring](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/previews/v2/provisioning/device/samples/solutions/BestPracticeSampleX509#warning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The authentication for the devices will show as "X509 CA Signed" rather than "Self-Signed X509 Certificate" once you obtain a legitimate certificate from a reliable Certified Authority. Please refer to this resource X.509 certificate [attestation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/concepts-x509-attestation). (or) We need to add the root CA certificate to the [IoT Hub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-dps/tutorial-custom-hsm-enrollment-group-x509.md). You can add the root CA certificate by selecting + Add in the Certificates section of the IoT Hub and uploading the root CA certificate file. Make sure to select the box next to Set certificate status to verified on [upload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/tutorial-x509-test-certs?tabs=linux). If you didn't choose to automatically verify the certificate during upload, you can manually prove possession by generating a verification code and creating a certificate that contains the verification code. You can then upload the verification certificate to your provisioning service in the Certificate Details dialog and select [Verify](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-dps/concepts-x509-attestation.md).

- Sample example Provision X.509 devices to Azure IoT Hub using a DPS enrollment [group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/tutorial-custom-hsm-enrollment-group-x509?tabs=linux&pivots=programming-language-csharp)
  --   Used this link for  `az iot dps enrollment-group`  from  [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/iot/dps/enrollment-group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-iot-dps-enrollment-group-compute-device-key).
- Replace the your resourcegroupname, dpsname,  [enrollment_id](https://i.imgur.com/w9kT2n9.png),  [registration_id](https://i.imgur.com/sQlXvaE.png). It gives  `derived-device-key`  or  `PROVISIONING_SYMMETRIC_KEY`.

`az iot dps enrollment-group compute-device-key -g {resourcegroupname} --dps-name {dpsname} --enrollment-id {enrollmentid} --registration-id {registrationid}`

- Above steps are for Provision a simulated symmetric key [device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/quick-create-simulated-device-symm-key)
- Code reference Provision multiple X.509 devices using enrollment [groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/tutorial-custom-hsm-enrollment-group-x509?tabs=linux&pivots=programming-language-csharp)

[image]

- Refer to this for azure-docs/articles/iot-dps/tutorial-custom-hsm-enrollment-group-x509.md at [main](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/iot-dps/tutorial-custom-hsm-enrollment-group-x509.md).

Comment: Hello. Thank you for answer.

I've added and verify my certificates to the IoT Hub and DPS, but my device still appears self signed (I'm not using X509 thumbprints). I think it's the same problem described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1132027/dps-enrollment-to-iothub-with-self-signed-vs-ca-ce)

Maybe it's because my root CA is self signed ? Or naming problem between DPS and IoT Hub ?

Comment: @ThéoBrilland Yes, it same problem He also said that Once you get a valid certificate from a trusted Certified Authority, the authentication for the devices will display as 'X509 CA Signed' instead of 'Self-Signed X509[Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1132027/dps-enrollment-to-iothub-with-self-signed-vs-ca-ce).